# what is inverse function of $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}$

Tags: calculus

what is inverse function of $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}$

---

I know that : $f : \mathbb{R} \to A$ So we have $f^{-1}: R_{f} \to \mathbb{R}$ that $R_f$ is range of function $f$ . now 
$$x=\dfrac{f^{-1}(x)}{1+|f^{-1}(x)|}$$
$$x+x|f^{-1}(x)|=f^{-1}(x) \\ x|f^{-1}(x)|-f^{-1}(x)+x=0$$

Now How is it found $f^{-1}(x) ?$

Answer (score 8):

This function is odd, so its inverse is too. Since $|f|=\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}$, $|x|=\frac{|f|}{1-|f|}$. Therefore, $x=\frac{f}{1-|f|}$.

Answer (score 2):

I would distinguish the cases $$x\geq 0$$ then our $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$$ and in the other case: $$x<0$$ we have
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}\implies|f(x)|=\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}<1$$
$$\implies|x|=\frac{|f|}{1-|f|}$$
Note that the denominator is always positive. We cannot conclude
$$x=\frac{f}{1-|f|}$$
yet, though it is tempting, because it may happen that $x=\frac{f}{1-|f|}$ at some points and $x=\frac{-f}{1-|f|}$ at some other points. So it is best to verify directly
$$\frac{f}{1-|f|}=\frac{\frac{x}{1+|x|}}{1-\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}}=\frac{x}{1+|x|-|x|}=x$$